# Globalizing dynamic values which are coming from DB in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

I have few values that are DB driven/or coming from other system which i dont have control of, So how to apply globalization in this case? I really dont trust on translation service apis that are provided from google or microsoft as i dont want any mistranslation happening anywhere in application leading to great embarassment to user.

So what is the best solution to tackle this schenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't expect miracles and don't look for a function in .NET called `string Translate(string input, string inputLanguage, string outputLanguage)`. If you don't want to use third party translation services because you don't trust them and you have no control over the data publisher so that it provide you with translations of the content on different languages there's really not much you could do. If it's simple words you could keep a dictionary in order to perform the translation on the fly but that will be impractical for whole sentences.

Comment: +1. The technology isn't there to do this perfectly and automatically. You don't trust large companies with their own research into this technology -- and yet they're the ones that have reached the furthest. The sad truth is that you're not going to do better, and it's probably going to be easier to just deal with the root cause instead of expecting magic to make everything work out. If you know you're only going to deal with a constrained set of values, do the translation correctly by hand and just look up the correct translation.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this in one of my products and what I did was to allow in the database design room for A)"native"/"original" + B)zero-ormany translations/localiazations of each such value. I've got in place a back end interface that allows for translating these values. That could be purely human-driven, or a combination of automatic translation with human verification.